# multiple image upload with jquery ajax without clicking any button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

I have written a script where I can upload multiple images with jquery ajax php..Here is the jquery and html part

```
$(function () {
    var form_control = $('#myForm');

     $('#myform').on('click', '.upload', function(){   
            var form = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'image_send_form.php',
                type: 'POST',
                 beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                 $("#gif").show();
            },
                success: function (r) {

                    $("#gif").hide();
                    $('.container_upload_form').html(r);

            },

            data:form,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
            $('.confirm_upload').show();
        });
    });


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">    
<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple name="image[]" id="image" />
<input type="button" value="Upload images" class="upload" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="close_upload"/>
```

This script works perfect..  But I want to do something different.. I dont want any submit button..I mean according to this code if I have to upload any image first I have to select it and then click the button to upload..What I want is when I select any image it will automatically get uploaded!! Just like facebook profile picture! We dont have to click any button to upload over there! Any help?..

Comment: To accomplish this, you have to bind a change event in the input with type=file. You get all files in **this.files** array.

Comment: Are you Looking for this type of uploader ? It's very easy to use... http://valums.com/files/2010/file-uploader/demo.htm